# How to stop people going to particular URLs in Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

Say I have the url `/product/view/1` which means I have the method in my product controller class:

```
function view($id)
{
    // Do something here
}
```

How do I get it to graciously fail if someone goes to `/product/view`?

Currently I'm getting two error messages, one saying `Missing argument 1 for Budget::view()` and one saying `Undefined variable: id` both of which I would expect, but obviously I'd rather provide my own one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if your controller is product, and method is view

```
...
function view ( $id = null ) {
  // set graciously failing if $id = null to avoid error 
  // and make happend what you want
  ....
}
...
```

Comment: Prefect. Thanks. Forgot about the default parameter.

Answer (score 4):

Two ways,

Option one: Give a default value for the `$id` variable by saying

```
function view($id = '')
{
     // Do something here and test if it's empty
}
```

This is what is traditionally done with optional parameters for functions in PHP

Option two: Rather than passing in the URI segment to the function as a parameter, you could alternatively get it using the URI helper (autoloaded by default)

```
function view()
{
     $id = (int) $this->uri->segment(3);
     // Do something here
}
```

Then you could test whether the id is set and do it from there

Answer (score 1):

Don't know about any CodeIgniter specifics, but you can always redirect with `.htaccess` and `mod_rewrite`

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/product/view$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/your-error-document [R=301,NC,L]
```

Comment: Good answer, but I was looking for something code based so I don't have to manage stuff server side every time I need to do something similar. Thanks though.

Comment: Fair enough. An advantage is that the user is being redirected before he hits the whole PHP processing .. (and therefore less load is put on the server)

Comment: That's actually a really good point. However, there won't be any links to the /products/view page so it would only be reachable if you wanted to mess with the URL. Having said that, it's probably worth logging when it does happen and if it happens a lot then I'll start using the .htaccess file.

Answer (score 1):

```
function view($id = false)
{
    if ($id===false) {
        //show error
        show_error('your error');
        //or redirect
    }
    // Do something here
}
```